# Include python version in requirements.txt?

Tags: python, python-3.x, github, repository

I am new to python but have written a small console application to help me analyse some data held in text files. I am not using any external dependencies and the program is written using python 3.6. Following best practices, should i include a requirements.txt file in my repository?

Although this is for personal use i would like to include it as a repository on github. At the moment my repository looks like:

```
- start.bat
- README.txt
- LICENCE.txt
- lambing_stats/__init__.py
- lambing_stats/lambing_stats.py
- lambing_stats/stats.txt
- tests.py
```

For a small single module console application, is this directory structure acceptable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That why we use a `readme.txt` right? You can include the required version there. [**Here**](https://gist.github.com/kipyegonmark/89fe62493f22d93705d917d634d8eeb2) is a good explanation of what a "good readme file" is. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, i have included a lot of that info in the readme file but thats a great link! Ive just been reading a few books about python that suggest setup files and requirement files are mandatory or at least very importand, and im just trying to gauge the roles of these files and their importance/relevance in my context with this small project!